# Scale PDF to width of iframe/object in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

The short question is;
"Can I - in Safari - on iPad (exclusively - no need for other browsers or devices) - scale a PDF document up or down to fit a fixed-width iframe or object tag?"

And the long question;
I have the following markup - used to display a scrollable PDF within a DIV. This markup is to be used in a Cordova/Phonegap app for iPad. Javascript smarts are via Backbone;

```
<div class="pdf-container-outer">
    <div class="pdf-container">
        <iframe src="..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

And the associated CSS (cut down for readability);

```
.pdf-container-outer {
    width: 800px; 
    height: 800px; 
    overflow: scroll !important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; 
}

.pdf-container { 
    width: 800px; 
}

iframe { 
    width: 800px; 
}
```

The PDF documents themselves are A4 sized - and the pixel dimensions of a pdf page then work out to be 595px X 841px. In Safari - the documents are always displayed at '100%' - i.e. regardless of the width I set on the iframe (or object tag - the results are the same), the inner PDF that appears is always only ~595px wide (+ about a 7-8px margin either side). They do not zoom.

The iframe width needs to change depending on whether or not the user is viewing the site in portrait or landscape mode... ~800px in landscape and ~520px in portrait.

Given that I know the number of pages in the documents I'm displaying - I DO know the full dimension of an iframe required to show all of the document. So one of the techniques I have toyed with, is setting the size of the iframe with some inline styles, and then applying a transform to it - to scale it up, a la;

```
<iframe src="..." style="width: 610px; height: 14000px; -webkit-transform: scale(1.31); -webkit-transform-origin: top left;" />
```

I.e. The applied transform scales 610px up by 131% = 800px wide (in landscape mode). In portrait - the scale factor is about 0.8.

This actually works quite well in Safari that comes with iOS6, but not so great in iOS5.1 - there are clipping problems that I cannot seem to get around - and so the solution is not ideal.

I'm sure that I'm overthinking it - and that there is a simpler solution. But for the life of me, I cannot get a PDF to scale width-wise in an iframe in Safari...

Little help?